# AngularJS input type=number default value

Tags: html, angularjs

New to Angular, and have this simple issue cannot get resolved:
I have this html

```
<input type="number" max="20" step="0.1" name="est_mpg" id="est_mpg" data-ng-model="est.mpg" class="form-control" value="5.00" />
```

I cannot get default value to show up, what happens it flashes and than disappears, so the box is empty, and i can tick up/down from default min value.
It worked fine until I turned the input to type="number" from text.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use GruffBunny' solution or as an alternative use `ng-init` instead of `value`:

```
 ng-init="est.mpg=5.00"
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aY8rE/

Answer (score 7):

Default the value of est.mpg to 5.00 in the controller and remove the value attribute.